Neutron absorbtion in Nuclear Fuel
Lets imagine we have a fuel rod surrounded by a moderator.
The neutron flux inside of the fuel (B) is given by
$$
D_B \Delta \Phi_B-\Sigma_{A, B} \Phi_B=0
$$
where $\Sigma_A$ is the absorbtion cross section.
Inside of the moderator neutron flux is given by
$$
D_M \Delta \Phi_M-\Sigma_{A, M} \Phi_M+q_{t h}=0 .
$$
Converting to cylindrical coordinates gives
$$
D_M \Delta \Phi_M-\Sigma_{A, M} \Phi_M+q_{t h}=0 .
$$
and
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \Phi_M}{\mathrm{~d} r^2}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{~d} \Phi_M}{\mathrm{~d} r}-\kappa_M^2 \Phi_M+\frac{q_{t h}}{D_M}=0 .
$$
solving the first equation gives a superposition of the first and bessel functions of the first and second kind. Because the neutron flux is finite only the first order bessel function remains:
$$
\Phi_B(r)=A I_0\left(\kappa_B r\right)
$$
and inside of the moderator we get the full superposition:
$$
\Phi_M(r)=A^{\prime} I_0\left(\kappa_M r\right)+C^{\prime} K_0\left(\kappa_M r\right) + \frac{q_{t h}}{\Sigma_{A, M}}
$$
which is the superposition of the bessel functions of the first and second kind of zerost order plus the particular solution.
The neutron profile should look like this:

where "Brennstoff" is the fuel.
However the Bessel function of the first kind looks like this:

So I do not understand how it is possible to get the minimum inside of the fuel. Because the neutron flux can not be negative. But if $A$ was negative, we would get a neutron flux below 0 at the center of the fuel. The first order bessel function $J_1$ (or $I_1$) doesnt solve the PDE. We might need something like $\Phi_B = - I_0(x) + C$, but that is not possible because there is no source term.
Does someone know how it is possible to obtain the solution with the drop in thermal neutrons shown in the image?

$I_n$ and $J_n$ are not the same function.  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

The Differential equation here is actually not the bessel Differential equation
$$
x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}+x \frac{d y}{d x}+\left(x^2-\alpha^2\right) y=0
$$
but the modified Bessel equation
$$
x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}+x \frac{d y}{d x}-\left(x^2+n^2\right) y=0 .
$$
(notice the minus sign).
They look like this

